# Add several links between two nodes in amcharts force directed network

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4, knowledge-graph

I'm using amcharts force directed network to render a knowledge graph.
In this knowledge graph two nodes can have multiple edges in each direction.

For example:

A "person" can be "born in" a city.

Also,

A "person" can "live in" a city.

From reading the documentation, I can make links between the edges using "linkWith", but I can't add a "type" and add more links.

[Example of two nodes with two link types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Aln.png)

Here is a sample of the json file:

```js
{
  "id": "200",
  "type": "City",
  "name": "New York",
  "color": "#2CB186",
  "linkWith": [{
    "115": ["born_in", "lives_in"]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want

```
                _label:lives_               
               /             \
  (node:'John')               (node:'New York')
               \__label:born_/
```

It isn't capable of that. no parrallel relationships between two nodes
the best you can do is make the labels into nodes and connect them like this.

```
               __(node:'lives')_
              /                 \
 (node:'John')                   (node:'New York')
              \__(Node:'Born')__/
```

I know its likely not ideal, also maybe look into https://www.amcharts.com/demos/transport-metro-map/ you can build relationships with multiple line segments between the same node.

Comment: Thank you, it's a clever workaround, although a little far fetched :)